My magento 2 store is running this process make cpu is very high
I have and issuse with my magento 2 store
the server has running this query and make the cpu to high,about 5-800% cpu ,



Hey,
Try once to disable all the third party modules and check cpu usage. also check reindexing rpocess time in ssh terminal.

I disable module auto relate and it gone to nomarl,
